# PHP DateTime Error / File Last Modified

Tags: php, datetime

For a file upload script (HTML5 File API / PHP creates the file out of the uploaded chunks) i need to convert the last modified date of a file to a Mysql Datetime format ('Y-m-d H:i:s'). The part in my PHP code looks like this:

```
// The last modified date is in a POST Request (jQuery AJAX)
$fileLastModified = new DateTime($_POST['fileLastModified']);
// Convert to UTC
$fileLastModified->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
// Change the format                    
$done = $fileLastModified->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

On OSX 10.9 (Mavericks) everything works and `$_POST['fileLastModified']` is set to a string like

> Wed Feb 26 2014 13:42:22 GMT+0100 (CET)

On a PC (Windows 8) `$_POST['fileLastModified']` is set to something like

> Wed Feb 26 2014 13:42:22 GMT+0100 (W. Europe Standard Time)

and PHP is giving me a very long error message (code above)

> 'Exception' with message 'DateTime::_*construct(): Failed to parse
>   time string (Wed Feb 26 2014 13:42:22 GMT+0100 (W. Europe Standard
>   Time)) at position 38 (E): Double timezone specification' in
>   /FILEPATH/upload.php:57\nStack trace:\n#0 /FILEPATH/upload.php(57):
>   DateTime->*_construct('Wed Feb 26 2014...')

So... why does DateTime fail to parse the string on a PC, whereas it works perfectly on OSX?

Comment: `W. Europe Standard Time` is not valid.

Comment: @JohnConde Thanks, any suggestions how to remove only that part? So that it still works for every file modified date?

Comment: Have you tried using http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strptime.php and specify expected date format, since this function would ignore all unrecognized elements?

Comment: @D.Kasipovic Not yet, since my knowledge in PHP is very limited, DateTime seemed like the easiest solution to convert the date to UTC time and change the format to whatever i want. Will need to find out how to do the same with `strptime`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DateTime::createFromFormat()` should allow you to selectively pick the parts of the date you want to use:

```
$date = str_replace('+', ' +', 'Wed Feb 26 2014 13:42:22 GMT +0100 (W. Europe Standard Time)');
$fileLastModified = DateTime::createFromFormat('D M d Y H:i:s e O+', $date);
$fileLastModified->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone('UTC'));                
echo $fileLastModified->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

[See it in action](http://codepad.viper-7.com/zy8Ckf)

I had to put a space before the `+` character as that broken DateTime's parsing of that string for some reason.

Comment: Thanks, i tried your code and added `$fileLastModified->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');` as per http://www.php.net/manual/de/datetime.createfromformat.php.

But PHP doesn't seem to like that for whatever reason: "Call to a member function format() on a non-object in ..."

Comment: Let me throw this in a fiddle and see what happens

Comment: Thanks a lot! Works now for both Windows and OSX